# StackOverflow Post Close and Locked with Ambiguous Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, locked, ambiguous-tags

The tag Access is ambiguous in that it can refer to the product MS Access or simply be a noun. Various members have carefully removed the tag Access when it appears, however, [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329869/what-rights-does-an-employer-have-to-the-employees-computer-closed) has been closed and locked with this tag, which means that posts tagged Access are turning up more regularly.

To avoid similar problems, perhaps tags could be cleared from posts before they are closed, locked or moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I deleted that post and rebuilt the tag counts.